# Can two flask functions use the same jinja2 template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have two flask routes which need to work with one function. The function is just a list of users styled as a radio button.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}List Users{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="w3-container">
    <h1 class='w3-padding-16' style="margin-top: 32px;">User List</h1>

<--! But what if the template was invoked from auth.select? How can I post back to the right function? -->
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('auth.all')}}">
        {% if users %}
            {% for user in users %}
                <div>
                    {% if user.email %}
                    <input class"" type="radio" id="choice_{{ user.id }}"
                                   name="selection" value="{{ user.id }}">
                            <label for="choice_{{ user.id }}">{{ user.User }}"("{{ user.first }} {{ user.last }}")"</label>
                    {% else %}
                        <p>Username: {{ user.User }}"(unregistered)"</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <h2>No users found in database.</h2>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="w3-bar w3-padding-16">
           <button type='submit' class="w3-button w3-black">Select</button>
           <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}" class="w3-button w3-black">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}ype here
```

I've searched around for the right url_for() arguments to express url_for('post_back to the function who called me'), but I'm spinning my wheels.

Comment: Have you considered just omitting the action attribute? If the template is served by the same route that the form should be sent to, this could be a possibility.

Comment: You can also use [`request.endpoint`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.endpoint) to specify the endpoint of the request.

Comment: Instead of using ```url_for```, pass a parameter for the url where form submit should go, back to the html page e.g. you could have a parameter called ```action_url```, you provide a value for ```action_url``` in both of your functions and then in your form, you have ```<form method="POST" action="{{ action_url}}">```

Comment: request.endpoint was what I was looking for. Thanks.